# cakephp 2 retrieve data with primary key as key

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I use cake a lot, and generally it gives me DB data back in a reasonable structure.

However sometimes I would like the data to be returned with the primary key of the DB as the key in the array. Cake insist on a separate primary key so is there any reason why cake can't/won't do the following:

```
$this->data = array(2 => array('PK' => 2, 'name' => 'Item 2'))
```

rather than:

```
$this->data = array(0 => array('PK' => 2, 'name' => 'Item 2'))
```

?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I know about 'list' but this is no good as I regularly need more than just 1 element in the 'value' bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something similar to this:

```
$myModels = $this->MyModel->find('all', [
    'fields' => [...],
    'joins' => [...],
    ...
]);

$result = Set::combine($myModels, '{n}.MyModel.id', '{n}.MyModel');
```

See also here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::combine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find('list')` query to retrieve your data with primary key as key of array.

It will return data as

```
[1]=>Item1
 [2]=>Item2
 .........
 ........
 ........
 ........
[n]=>ItemN
```

[Read manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list)

Comment: The problem with list is that it loses some of the join relationships when you use it. This I have tried and verified. Also, sometimes I need more than just a single value for the 'Item' part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find('list') function of the cakephp to get primary key as key element of the array.This url mayhelp you to do it properly.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html